# Json - Mysql Charset Problem

Tags: php, mysql, json, utf-8

I convert my php array to json using json_encode, Than I record this json data to my database .While json_encode encodes my data , It also converts strings to utf8 , this changes special characters to something like  '/u011f' or '/u0131' . But when I write this converted data to mysql database , Backslashes are disappearing in field, so when I get this data back , html can not render characters correctly.

What should I do to keep backslashes.

Comment: Make sure you're always using mysql_real_escape_string or pdo/mysqli prepared statements, actually. This is really important to avoid SQL injection attacks as well as other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to escape string data before sending database so that mysql does not treat backslashes as an escape character.

Answer (score 2):

Use mysql_real_escape_string to escape the string before inserting it into the database.

```
escapedJSON = mysql_real_escape_string(jsonEncodedString);
```